# how to install channels redis in django using pip without errors

Tags: python, django

I am trying to install channels redis module using pip but so far am still getting errors.
I installed Microsoft c++ build tools as the error suggested but so far the error still persists when it comes to building wheel for hiredis.
Here is the output error.

```html
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for hiredis did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [25 lines of output]
      C:\Users\Teacher-5F84DF\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cs726k2z\hiredis_fa16ee7f0b4e4df28a1a34d9640a827d\setup.py:7: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib and slated for removal in Python 3.12; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
        import sys, imp, os, glob, io
      c:\users\teacher-5f84df\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:697: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'description_file' instead
        warnings.warn(
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\hiredis
      copying hiredis\version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\hiredis
      copying hiredis\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\hiredis
      copying hiredis\hiredis.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\hiredis
      copying hiredis\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\hiredis
      running build_ext
      building 'hiredis.hiredis' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\src
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\vendor
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\vendor\hiredis
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ivendor -Ic:\users\teacher-5f84df\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\include -Ic:\users\teacher-5f84df\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\Include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include /Tcsrc\hiredis.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\src\hiredis.obj
      hiredis.c
      c:\users\teacher-5f84df\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> hiredis

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Please assist.Thank you

Comment: You're using windows. `hiredis` only supports Linux & Mac. According yo [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/hiredis/)

Comment: how will i then incorporate RedisChannellayer in Django in windows then ?